# MSVC builds the code, while g++ and clang fail with ambiguous operator= error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, clang++

I've created the following sample, which compiles on MSVC (2015, 2017) while it fails on g++ and clang. While I am aware how to circumvent the problem (use explicit cast instead of implicit), I am wandering which compiler is closer to the standard regarding this sample?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A {
    std::string a;
};

struct B {
    std::string b1;
    std::string b2;
};

struct C {
    int c;
};

class test
{
public:
    std::string t_a;
    std::string t_b1;
    std::string t_b2;
    int t_c;

    template <class ValueT>
    operator ValueT() const
    {
        ValueT tmp;
        get_values(*this, tmp);
        return  tmp;
    };
};

void get_values(const test& t1, A& a)
{
    a.a = t1.t_a;
};

void get_values(const test& t1, B& b)
{
    b.b1 = t1.t_b1;
    b.b2 = t1.t_b2;    
};

void get_values(const test& t1, C& c)
{
    c.c = t1.t_c;
};

template<class Base1, class Base2>
class Mixin : public Base1, public Base2
{
public:
    virtual Mixin& operator= (const Base1& p) { Base1::operator=(p); return     *this; }
    virtual Mixin& operator= (const Base2& p) { Base2::operator=(p); return *this; }

    virtual void merge(const Base1& p1, const Base2& p2) {
        *this = p1;
        *this = p2;
    }
};

template<class Base1, class Base2>
void get_values(const test& j, Mixin<Base1, Base2>& p)
{
    Base1 b1 = j;
    Base2 b2 = j;
    p.merge(b1, b2);
}

using mixed = Mixin<A, Mixin<B,C>>;

int main() 
{
    test tt {
        "123",
        "456",
        "789",
        10
    };

    mixed m{};
    m = tt;

    std::cout << m.a << " " << m.c << "\n";
}
```

I would appreciate any clue regarding this sample.

Comment: I'm not sure how MSVC manages to compile this. `Mixin` has two user-defined overloads of `operator=`, plus the implicitly declared ones. And `tt` can convert to any type. There's no possible basis on which to prefer one assignment over another. Looks like a bug in MSVC to me.

Comment: Exactly, tt can convert to any, including mixed. So MSVC use generated copy assignment, and implicitly uses user-defined conversion from tt to mixin. Changing the line "m = tt" to "m = mixin(tt)"" is enough for g++ and clang to select generated copy assignment.So I think you're right, as all overloads should be equal and compiler is not entitled to choose between them.